# pentaho schema workbench time dimension foreign key base

Tags: schema, pentaho, mondrian, workbench

In my schema I have a time dimension based on foreing key, that conects with fact table. When displayed values like years at column and month at row the values are showed like image [image: Year column X Months on row]

How I do to group in the same row all month's? Is there a way to do that by schema workbench?

schema workbench Product Version : 3.12.0.1-196

Comment: The result you are getting is proper only.
because of foreign key it is considering it as a Jan-2014 to dec-2014,jan-2015 to dec-2015 so on and so forth.
so you need to change your logic in a way you are creating schema structure in order to get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you did not define the month and year as unique members, this is defined at the time of creating the level, you cant look this[schema workbench documantation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php), this only work if you dont have error in the logic,greetings